# Is there an any way to do get range

Tags: javascript, php

For example, I have here the data in the database

id  range  price

1. 1-3   30
2. 4-8     50
3. 9-13    80
4. 14-20   120
5. 21-29   160

I want that when the user inputs any number the price will display depending on the ranged.

For example, the user input number 5, since 5 belongs to the range of 4-8 the 80 will display as price. another example is when the user inputs number 23 the 160 will display as price since 23 belongs to the range of 21-29.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Javascript:**

You could build an *array of objects* with the ***price*** and ***range*** as *keys* where the **price** is the *key* of the prices *value* and ***range*** is an *array of constraints* for the **start** and **finish** of that section.

Then *iterate* over the possible objects that exist in the array and see if the `ID` falls within the constraints using a *conditional* that checks if the ***low number*** of the range, `range[0]` is *less than or equal to* the `ID` AND the ***high number*** of the range, `range[1]` is *greater than or equal to* the ID. When you get a match use `range.price` to get the ***price*** value within the range.

```js
const userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput");
const checkPrice = document.querySelector("#checkPrice");
const price = document.querySelector("#price");
const ranges = [{
    price: 30,
    range: [1, 3]
  },
  {
    price: 50,
    range: [4, 8]
  },
  {
    price: 80,
    range: [9, 13]
  },
  {
    price: 120,
    range: [14, 20]
  },
  {
    price: 160,
    range: [21, 29]
  }
]

function getIdRangesPrice(e) {
  const id = userInput.value;
  ranges.forEach((range, i) => range.range[0] <= id && range.range[1] ? price.textContent = `$${range.price}` : null)
}

checkPrice.addEventListener('click', getIdRangesPrice)

/*If you want to get the next price level do the following
  ranges.forEach((range, i) => range.range[0] <= id && range.range[1] >= id && ranges[i + 1] !== undefined ? price.textContent = `$${Object.values(ranges[i + 1])[0]}` : null)
*/
```

```html
<input id="userInput" min="1" max="29" type="number"><button id="checkPrice">Check Price</button>
<div id="price"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have database with column start and end

with 1 as start and 3 as end

you can run query select price from rangeTable where $userInput between start and end

Comment: can you please me about the code.

Comment: sure split the ranged column in two columns named start end, and $userInput is where you will replace user value

Comment: ok thanks I get it....thank you....show me using javascript and php

Comment: glad to know that

Comment: it's database query either nodejs or PHP can be used, are you using some framework or custom call?

Comment: I'm using some framework

Comment: good, see examples of that framework to query database, I have written the query for your help